# What is the domain?

Tags: functions

what is the domain of $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}?$ I'm trying to understand why x cannot be equal to zero in addition to whether we have to specify and endpoint for the domain.

Comment: Why $x$ cannot be $0$? What is $1$ divided by $0$? How many zeros do you need to make $1$? Can it be done?

Comment: [Wheel theory](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_theory) might be of interest to you.

Comment: I despise the way these questions are often written in textbooks.  A correct way of asking the question is "*what is the maximal subset of $\Bbb R$ which can be taken as a domain of the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$?*"  The end result for this specific question is that division by zero is not defined, however division by any other real number is defined... so the maximal subset of $\Bbb R$ which can act as a domain is very simply $\Bbb R\setminus \{0\}$, the nonzero real numbers, otherwise notated as $(-\infty,0)\cup (0,\infty)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mathematics, the domain or set of departure of a function is the set into which all of the input of the function is constrained to fall.

Please check here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function